# AdS/CFT dual of $N$ D$p$-branes at finite temperature

Tags: black-holes, temperature, ads-cft, branes, duality

The gravity dual of $N$ D$p$-branes at zero temperature is

$$ ds^2= H^{-1/2}(r)(-dt^2+dx_p^2) + H^{1/2}(r)(dr^2 + r^2d\Omega_{8-p}^2) $$

with

$$ H(r) = 1 + \left(\frac{R}{r}\right)^{7-p} $$

what is (tell me if I'm wrong) an extremal black $p$-brane.

When we consider that the boundary system is at temperature $T$, the dual metric then is

$$ ds^2= H^{-1/2}(-h(r)dt^2+dx_p^2) + H^{1/2}\left(\frac{dr^2}{h(r)} + r^2d\Omega_{8-p}^2\right) \qquad(*)$$

with

$$ h(r) = 1 + \left(\frac{r_0}{r}\right)^{7-p} $$

(for example, this is written [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0605073), in section 7.5, for $p=3$), but I don't know to what system corresponds this metric, except for $p=3$, which is an AdS black hole (for $r$ near the throat).

So the question is, what system has the metric $(*)$?

Answer (score 2):

AdS black holes exist in various dimensions, $p=3$ is not the only choice. The parameter can take on values above or below $3$. One famous example is the three-dimensional BTZ black hole, and higher dimensional ones are also frequently used in the correspondence.

Furthermore, I think there is a misunderstanding on the concept of a "gravity dual". The metric you wrote down is not the the gravity dual of a $\mathrm{D}p$-brane at zero temperature, it is a solution of classical gravity that corresponds to the geometry of such a brane at low energies. In this sense, it *is* the D-brane in a particular limit. The word "gravity dual" refers to precisely this geometry, and it is the dual of a quantum field theory living on its boundary. The AdS/CFT correspondence is about formulating higher-dimensional gravity duals (D-Branes and their low energy limits) of quantum field theories in lower dimensions.

Comment: But for $p\neq 3$ the first metric is not AdS.

If I understood correctly your answer, the metric (*) corresponds to a black hole in the spacetime of the first metric?

Comment: Your statement is not true, AdS is not restricted to $p=3$.